# How to dynamically create JavaScript variable based on string value?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

How can I dynamically create a variable whose name is based on a given string value? For example:

```
var name = 'jayesh';
var value = 'some value';

// ... do something

console.log(jayesh); // prints 'some value'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question here. Hint: What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: I think you want `something[name]`

Comment: i want to define 'jayesh' as variable

Comment: var jayeshvalue = 0; eval(name+" = "+jayeshvalue);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an object like this.

```
var obj = {};
var name = 'jayesh';
obj[name] = 'some value';
var myvalue = obj.jayesh;
```

You can create a global variable like this:

```
var name = 'jayesh';
window[name] = 'some value';
```

You can also use eval but this can cause security issues so use with caution!

```
var name = 'jayesh';
var evalString = 'var ' + name + ' = "some value"';
eval(evalString);
```

Comment: first one is better.

Comment: Much agreed sir, thats why I put it on top. Only way I would use although I am confused as to why he must have a variable dynamically named that.

Comment: may be just for fun....^^